# Problema com a biblioteca Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou aprendendo python e estou fazendo um programa que gera gráficos a partir de um arquivo CSV, porem toda vez que eu tento usar a função `savefig()`, ele salva os dados com as labels dos anteriores, porém se antes de eu usar essa função, usar a função `show()`, esse erro não acontece, o que eu devo fazer para arrumar isso?

```
    def  SalvaGraficos(self,lista,name):
         import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
         from collections import Counter
         import os
         import shutil
         contador = Counter(lista)

         dadosnome = []
         dadosvalor = []

         for chave, valor in contador.items():
              dadosnome.append(chave)
              dadosvalor.append(valor)
         print(dadosnome)
         self.nomeGrafico = str(self.valorImagem)+".png"
         dirImagem = str(self.caminho) + "/" + self.nomeGrafico
         try:
              pl.pie(dadosvalor, labels=dadosnome, autopct='%1.1f%%')
              pl.title(name)
              pl.savefig(dirImagem) 

              self.valorImagem = self.valorImagem + 1
              print('Imagem Salva! Nome: '+self.nomeGrafico)
         except:
              print('erro ao salvar!')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se você usar a função `plt.close('all')`, funcionará. Eu faço dessa forma. Link para a documentação: [matplotlib.pyplot.close](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html)

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!